# performance of akka remote

Tags: scala, akka

I am using the akka-sample-remote sample to do some performance test. Seems the time for the roundtrip is 3ms now. which includes (two actor in two jvm in the same host using localhost).

1 A->B: send a MathOp request
2 B->A: send back the result

I suspect most of the time is spent on the serialization. But not sure. anyone have any suggestion how could I improve the performance further? Is it really the serialization that takes most of the time. Since they are on the same host. So I assume the network should not take much time?

Comment: It's the time of the MathOp operation included in the 3 ms or is it just a no-op?!

Comment: `3ms` is very less. What makes you think it is bad.

Comment: No, it's not serialization for such a simple communication.  Are you fluent in performance-testing?  For example, are you executing the test many times before starting measurements?

Comment: What Serializer are you using and how much warmup are you doing and how many samples are you taking and what do the 50th 75th 90th 99th and 99.9th percentiles look like?

Comment: @VincenzoMaggio. Originally it's included, I also tried to move it out of the measurement. But doesn't affect. since it's just add/subtract.

Comment: @Jatin, to be honest. I am not sure whether this is good or not. We are investigating whether akka remoting works well for latency sensitive situation. Since we plan to implement a small commertial bank system. So we need to reduce the latency as much as possible. So you think 3ms is kind of the limit of akka remoting performance?

Comment: @ViktorKlang, I am using the default Java serializer. I am measuring one by one, since I want to know if I use this to implement a trading system. How much it would take for an order to be executed (cross machine). Do you think using protobuf will improve the performance in this simple sample?

Comment: Java Serialization is horribly slow. Switch to Protobuf or Kryo if you want to make any meaningful benchmarking. Also, you'll have to run warmups and multiple runs and check percentiles.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that this is bad number?

Do not mix latency and throughput. Single-threaded system which has throughput 60k items per second does not have latency 1000/60k ms.

I've used Redis which is single-threaded app and it's able to consume ~100k messages per second but with 500+ concurrent connections. It does not provide nanosecond latency as it could see at first glance.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually I am worrying about the latency here not the throughput. I want to have a trading system. So I want to know whether the latency of akk remoting meets the performance required.

Comment: So you should read articles and presentation about Lmax and their disruptor pattern here in discussion or e.g. on infoq. They have also trading system and really care about latency in microseconds point of view. Very inspirative presentations including processor caches etc.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look. I am still open for any suggestions on this simple performance test. like 1: is it the best akka could do; 2 using protobuf will improve the performance in this simple communication;